# How to convert string to html?

Tags: html, angular, ckeditor

Posts in my web app are stored like html tags with text like b,br,span etc.
I'm using an angular editor for that.
How to convert that text in real html tags?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us what have you been achieved so far? It would make answering your question easier.

Comment: Can I add image for that ?

Comment: `b`, `br` and `span` tags are "real" HTML-tags

Comment: I store text with html tags but when I try to show those, it shows like string "<br>test</br>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use:

```
<div [innerHTML]="yourText"></div>
```

This will show yout html text as html.